# How to use require in the browser

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lob

I am trying to use RequireJS to use the require() function in the browser. For context, I am trying to work with the Node wrapper for the Lob API: https://github.com/hisankaran/lob-node.

Here's the relevant code:

```
define (function (require) {
        var LOB = require('lob');
        LOB = new LOB(API_KEY);
    })
    // var LOB = new (require('lob')) (API_KEY);
    console.log('Success?')
```

It runs successfully, but when I try to actually call anything, for example LOB.bankaccounts.create, it says LOB is not defined.

The Lob docs suggested that I do simply this:

```
var LOB = new (require('lob')) (LOB_API_KEY);
```

but I kept getting that the module had not yet been loaded for context error described here (http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded), so I tried the above syntax from the RequireJS website.

I'm super new to RequireJS (and coding in general), so I may just be doing something silly.

Comment: If you are using chrome, have a look in the network tab in dev tools. Are all files  requested and delivered as expected, or do you get some 404s or no requests at all?

Answer (score 3):

The `define()` function has to actually return the object it defines.

Furthermore, in the browser `require()` should be used asynchronously as the synchronous call only works, when the module has already been loaded.

That being said, I would restructure your code as follows:

```
define( ['lob'], function( LOB ){
  return new LOB( API_KEY );
});
```

Put that in some module definition and load it in your main module, e.g., like this

```
require( [ 'myLob' ], function( myLob ){
 // do something with myLob
});
```